# How do I use the orientationchange in jQuery Mobile when working with height?

Tags: jquery, mobile

In jQuery Mobile, I am trying to adjust the height of an image to the height of the window.  The height of the window depends on the orientation of the device, but I found out that whenever I change the orientation, the height of the window that is plugged into the expressions for the height of the image is the height of the window BEFORE the orientation change!  So, how do I make it so it picks up the height of the window AFTER the orientation change and then uses this new value to adjust the image height?

For the code I have

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange',function(e){
  if(window.orientation == 0)
  {
    $('img').css('width') = $(window).height()*.5;
  }
  else
  {
    $('img').css('width') = $(window).height()*.6;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use setTimeout

```
var fixHeight = function () {

    var bodyHeight = $(document.body).height();

};


$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (e) {
    setTimeout(fixHeight,200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-thinking this.  There are many different devices that are natively supported by the JQuery Mobile framework "out of the box".  Which means, you don't have to manually code for changes in the UI for corresponding orientation change events.  This built-in functionality should handle most of your UI presentation.

From the [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) documentation:
Viewport meta tag:
Note above that there is a meta viewport tag in the head to specify how the browser should display the page zoom level and dimensions. If this isn't set, many mobile browsers will use a "virtual" page width around 900 pixels to make it work well with exisitng desktop sites but the screens may look zoomed out and too wide. By setting the viewport attributes to content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, the width will be set to the pixel width of the device screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

These settings do not disable the user's ability to zoom the pages which is nice from an accessibility perspective. There is a minor issue in iOS that doesn't properly set the width when changing orientations with these viewport settings, but this will hopefully be fixed a a future release. You can set other viewport values to disable zooming if required since this is part of your page content, not the library.

I would start by removing your window.bind JQuery Mobile code and set the default viewport, as noted above.  Then, retest.  Let the framework help you and do what it was designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar and using relative (%) sizing for all my elements seems to be doing the trick. So I have a 5x3 grid of images, and the grid itself consists of a div sized at {width: 100%; height: 60%}, then 5 vertical columns, which are all divs with {width: 18%; height: 98%; margin: 1%} and then each cell is a div {width: 90%; height: 30%; margin: 5%}, and finally the image within the cell div is styled at {width: 100%; height: 100%}.

This is still in the dev stage and it remains to be seen how well it works when I start to add more complex decoration to the UI, and I might not have the percentages exactly right yet,  but at the moment I have it scaling nicely up and down.

And I also have the  tag described in the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile JQuery documentation 1.1 says that timing is different,
so you don't know if your window-var has old or new values, 
but also gives the information that:

" though the current implementation will give you the correct value for event.orientation derived from window.orientation"

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

So it should work when you change window.orientation to e.orientation:

```
if(e.orientation == 0)
{
    ...
}
```